# How to interpret elpd_diff of Bayesian LOO estimate in Bayesian Logistic Regression

Tags: r, bayesian, logistic, brms

I have conducted a Bayesian Logistic regression, and I would like to compare 2 models : one model with one continuous predictor (M1) and one model without predictor (M0). The outcome is a binary variable.

I have used LOO estimated of brms package.
I find following results :

Model comparisons:

```
                      elpd_diff se_diff
(M1)Bayes_Model_Binary  0.0       0.0   
(M0)modelLOO           -0.4       1.3
```

But how can I interpret that ?

Answer (score 2):

The table reports the difference in expected log predictive density (elpd) between each model and the best model as well as the standard error of this difference (assuming the difference is approximately normal). The values in the first row are 0s because the models are ordered from best to worst according to their elpd.

Elpd is a measure of the predictive accuracy of a model *on a new dataset* generated by the same data generating process as the data used for model fitting. Under certain conditions (the models are not badly misspecified, the models are not very similar and there are more than 100 observations), elpd_diff is approximately normally distributed with standard error se_diff. The rule of thumb is that the models are "very similar" if |elpd_diff| (the absolute value of elpd_diff) is less than 4.

In this case, elpd_diff is only 0.4 (and it's 3 times smaller than its SE though the normal approximation might not be reliable since the conditions do not hold), so we conclude the models M0 and M1 have the same predictive performance. In other words, adding the continuous predictor makes no difference (for prediction).

See also the [Cross-validation FAQ](https://users.aalto.fi/%7Eave/CV-FAQ.html) by Aki Vehtari and in particular the section [12 What is the interpretation of ELPD / elpd_loo / elpd_diff?](https://users.aalto.fi/%7Eave/CV-FAQ.html#12_What_is_the_interpretation_of_ELPD__elpd_loo__elpd_diff) and [16 How to interpret in Standard error (SE) of elpd difference (elpd_diff)?](https://users.aalto.fi/%7Eave/CV-FAQ.html#se_diff).