# Bayesian Logistic Regression with brms and comparison model with R

Tags: r, bayesian, logistic, inference, modeling

Yesterday, I asked how to conduct a Bayesian logistic regression in another post. I have been advised to use the brms R package.

I have conducted this analysis, but being a beginner in statistics and coding, I need to know if my analysis is right.

I have a data set with one binary outcome ("Object"). Participants had to choose between two objects. I want to check if this choice was not influenced by a continuous predictor ("PHQ").

First, I have fitted a bayesian logistic regression model with Non-Informative Priors following tutorial of Fang & Van de Shoot (https://www.rensvandeschoot.com/tutorials/generalised-linear-models-with-brms/).

[image]

Could you  help me to interpret these outputs?

- I see that the credibility interval contains the 0. Does could be in favour of an absence of effect of the predictor on the outcome?
- How to interpret estimate in a report?

Second I have repeat the procedure to fit e null model without predictor.
[image]

I have used the LOO function to compare the two models.
[image]
How can I interpret that? How is it informative for my hypothesis that PHQ (predictor) does not predict the binary outcome (Object)?

Thanks.

Comment: First, you would check that the MCMC sampling has converged (required before you draw inferences from the model fits). Things look good (no divergent transitions, Rhats are ~1), so you can proceed to the inference step.

Comment: Second, LOO compares the two models in terms of their prediction accuracy, so the elpd_diff result directly addresses the question whether PHQ predicts the outcome (in a situation where they aren't any other predictors). See [How to interpret elpd_diff of Bayesian LOO estimate in Bayesian Logistic Regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/608881/237901) for how to interpret elpd_diff.